# How properly pass redux selector to react-dnd drop-handler function?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs, redux-toolkit, react-dnd

I am spend a lot of time to manage how to combine fabricjs with react and react-dnd, and in the end I serialize Canvas in Redux store, and get it on demand. But I stuck in other issue, that I can not properly get my canvasJSON inside useDrop hook from react-dnd, it always return initial state of my selector. Could anyone help me what I am doind wrong? Below is my "Canvas" component:

```
import s from './Canvas.module.scss';

import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../../reduxHooks';
import { canvasSelector, setCanvasAction } from './canvas.slice';
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd'
import DraggableItems, { DraggableIdProps, DraggableTextTypes } from '../../types/DraggableItems';

const Canvas = (): JSX.Element => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const canvasJSON = useAppSelector(canvasSelector);

  const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: DraggableItems.text,
    drop: (item) => dropHandler(item as DraggableIdProps),
    collect: monitor => ({
      isOver: monitor.isOver(),      
    }),
  }))

  const initCanvas = () => {
    
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
      height: 350,
      width: 600,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    })

    console.log(canvas.toDatalessJSON(), 'canvas.toDatalessJSON()')
    dispatch(setCanvasAction(canvas.toDatalessJSON()))
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    initCanvas();
  }, []);

  function dropHandler(item: DraggableIdProps): void {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current);

    console.log(canvasJSON, 'JSON')
    canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasJSON, () => {
      console.log(canvas, 'done')
    })
    switch (item.id) {
      case DraggableTextTypes.heading:
        const text = new fabric.IText('HEADING', { left: 100, top: 50 });
        canvas.add(text);
        console.log(canvas, 'drop')
        break;
    
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  return (

    <div ref={drop}>
      {isOver ? 'Release to drop' : 'Drag a box here'}
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} id="editorCanvas" className={s.canvas} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Canvas;
```